# Show that $T$ is a linear transformation given Orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, orthonormal

Suppose that $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ and $\{Tv_1,Tv_2,\cdots,Tv_n\}$ are orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $T$ is a linear transformation.

Attempt:

I know that to show that $T$ is linear I must be able to show that given $u,v\in V$ I will have $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$. I must also show that $T(cu)=cT(u)$.

I also know that I can write $u=\sum_i (v_i,v)v_i$ or $u=\sum_i(Tv_i,v)Tv_i$.

Now I'm not sure how to proceed. Could somebody give me an idea? Thank you!

Comment: As already answered, it can't be proved $\;T\;$ is linear **unless** you give a complete definition on every element of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ , which you didn't. Had you added "...and extend by linearity the definition of $\;T\;$ " everything would be fine, though the question "prove it is a linear map" would then be utterly trivial. What isn't trivial is that $\;T\;$, if defined to be linear, is an isomorphism and, in fact, a unitary operator.

Answer (score 2):

From what you wrote, it does not follow that $T$ is a linear transformation. For example, if I have an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,v_2\dots,v_n\}$ for $\mathbb R^n$, then I can define $T$ as
$$T(w) = \begin{cases}v_i&\text{ if } w=v_i\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

This $T$ fits all the demands you wrote about $T$, but it is not linear.